# Java "Jackson" JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of float out of FIELD_NAME token

Tags: java, json, jackson

with this class:

```
public class Products implements Serializable {
    private BigDecimal productId;
    private float priority;

    public float getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(float priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }
}
```

When doing deserialization of such JSON data:

```
{"productId":47552,"priority":78}
```

Got this error:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: 
Can not deserialize instance of float out of FIELD_NAME token
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@103cf49; line: 1, \
 column: 290] (through reference chain: entity.Products["priority"])
```

But for this data (quotes around priority value)

```
{"productId":47552,"priority":"78"}
```

works well, so it seems that jackson (1.9.9) does not respect numeric values ? I suspect something is wrong here.

Comment: You sure the `long` type of your priority field is correct in your code example? You're using `float` in your getter and setter... If that code is your actual code, it might be the reason.

Comment: yes, that was typo, thank you

Comment: I cannot seem to reproduce it by simply using jackson 1.9.9 and trying to read/write a string value from a POJO as shown above. Which makes me think the actual error might be caused by the way you call jackson. Maybe it'll help to show us that code :).

Comment: Yes it used with jersey, so no custom code here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are declaring the field priority as a float type and you try to deserialize the Json which contains int value. Jackson try to call a setter function which accepts a integer value. So we need to add one setter like this.

```
public void setPriority(int priority){
    this.priority = Float.valueOf(priority);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you declared priority as long and getter and setter methods are using float.
can you check with

```
   public long getPriority() {
            return priority;
        }

        public void setPriority(long priority) {
            this.priority = priority;
        }
```